# nth child not working with within body

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to draw a 6x6 grid with divs, but when I create them with javascript and css, it doesn't show as expected.

css:

```
div{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
div:nth-child(6n+1){
    clear:both;
}
```

javascript:

```
for(var i=0; i<36; i++){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqzhorq0/

The above link demonstrates what I see in the browser.

But, when I select onload or onDomReady settings in jsfiddle, the grid shows as expected.

How can I get the grid to show properly using onload or onDomReady, and why isn't it showing properly without it?

Comment: Use :nth-of-type() instead.

Comment: As to why it doesn't show properly without it: the script will be run before the document is fully loaded so the body probably doesn't exist when that line is run

Comment: You can put your script in window.onload=function(){//script here}

Comment: Am I the only one here who thought this was a pregnancy question? ;-)

Comment: @wunth - that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can wrap your divs in a container and specify your selectors to target from within the container your code will work.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
for(var i=0; i<36; i++){
    document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
}
```

```css
#foo div{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:0px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
}

#foo div:nth-child(6n+1){
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

I also created an interactive demo on nth-child to help explain it further: http://xengravity.com/demo/nth-child/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, very nice demo!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, the first child of the body in the fiddle is the script element. You can inspect the html of the result panel to see the script element.

The [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) will consider all the elements while using the index to search for an element, but using [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) you can search for a particular type.

One choice is to use the :nth-of-type selector as below

```
div {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
div:nth-of-type(6n+1) {
    clear:both;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvfp1tyk/1)

---

Another is to insert the divs before the script like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), document.body.firstChild);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvfp1tyk/2/)

---

But a better solution will be use a custom container element instead of the body element

```
var ct = document.getElementById('container');
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    ct.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
}
```

then

```
#container > div {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
#container div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear:both;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvfp1tyk/3/)